# Codeigniter query where_in array

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have website with various filters including CATEGORY filter. User can choose multiple categories as well as one.
In MYSQL database, field for the 'po_category' is an array (64, 93, 97).
So, in codeigniter I have the following code:

```
$kategorija = $this->input->post('kategorija');

$this->db->select('*'); 
$this->db->from('jobs');

    if(!empty($kategorija)) {
        $cat_array = explode(',', $kategorija);
        $count_items = count($cat_array);
        
        
        
        if($count_items == '1') {
            $this->db->where("find_in_set($kategorija, po_category)");
        } else {
            $this->db->group_start();
            $count = 0;
            foreach($cat_array as $item) {
                $count++;
                
                if($count == '1') {
                    $this->db->where_in("find_in_set($item, po_category)");
            
                } else {
                    $this->db->or_where("find_in_set($item, po_category)");
                }
            }
            $this->db->group_end();
        }
    }
```

It works fine only if in filter I choose first number in category array (64).
I guess I have to use 'where_in' but it doesn't work as it should.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The `where_in` syntax for CodeIgniter is like this:

```
where_in('column', $array);
```

Why do you use find_in_set?

Comment: I tried it but still not working, when chosen category is on the first place in database filed, it fine: ie. when I choose category 2 and I have in database field 2, 7, 61, it's fine but if I choose 7, it's not showing

Comment: So, I tried with:
$this->db->where_in('po_category', $kategorija);

My 'po_category' field has value: 2, 7, 61, 333
and $kategorija value is 333
but result is empty

Comment: You said that the field for the 'po_category' is an array (64, 93, 97) in the database. You cannot have an array stored in the database, only text/json maybe. Is it text? Like "64, 93, 97" ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it's text field with string in it like "64, 93, 97"

Comment: Basically, I need to use where_in form chossen categories (2,5,8) and my category field in database look lik "3,5,11"

Answer (score 0):

You can replace following code:

```
foreach($cat_array as $item) {
  $count++;
            
  if($count == '1') {
      $this->db->where_in("find_in_set($item, po_category)");  
   } else {
      $this->db->or_where("find_in_set($item, po_category)");
   }
}
```

With [`where_in`](http://tutorialsmint.com/codeigniter-tutorial/codeigniter-where-in):

```
$this->db->where_in('po_category', $cat_array);
```